# How to perform the following insert, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, reports and events, each table has a unique identifier called id with Auto increment, the problem is that the id in each table is not the same because a report can have events but maybe not. I would like to make a double insert but one column in each table must have an unique key. I do this with the following function:

```
function addactioneventuser(){

        try {

             $this->conn->beginTransaction();

              $query = "INSERT INTO
                    " . $this->table_name . "
                SET
                    case_id = ?, 
                    from_to = 0, 
                    action_id = ?, 
                    accepted = 0, 
                    message = ?";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // bind values
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->case_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->action_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->message);



        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

    // insert event query
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO event_case

                SET 
                    title = ?, body = ?, class = ?, start = ?, end = ?, case_id= ?, worker_id = ?";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query2);

        // bind values
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->title);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->body);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->class_event);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $this->start);
        $stmt->bindParam(5, $this->end);
        $stmt->bindParam(6, $this->case_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(7, $this->worker_id);

    // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();   


    $this->conn->commit();
    return true;



} catch (Exception $e) {
  $stmt->rollBack();
  return false;
}

}
```

The two inserts works perfectly but my problem is that the two ids for each table are not the same and as a consequence I can not delete at the same time an specific record from both tables and I don't know how to do it. I read about Cascade and other possible solutions but none of them seem pausible for my problem. I don't mind to create another column to use it as reference for both tables but I don't know how to do it in the above query.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `last_insert_id()` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: Which is it: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: mysql, sorry I miss clicked the tag

Comment: If you need the same key, make it an auto-incrementing column in the leading table (case), get the inserted key (see Gordon's comment), and use that key when inserting a row in the child table (event_case). The column should not be auto-incremented in that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last insert id is `$this->conn->insert_id;`
You can get it after the operation and use the identifier. 
For example to add it to the desired table

Comment: But How I save the last insert from query1 and pass the value into query2. I don't unserstand how can I save that value in a transactional query.

Comment: You can be divided into two operations. After execute first query you can use id in second query